# Implicit moving in return statement requiring a conversion operation

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, move-semantics, conversion-operator

In C++20 there is a rule that informally known as "when returning a variable, first try to move, and only then copy".

More formally it is [`[class.copy.elision]/3`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.copy.elision#3)

> An *implicitly movable entity* is a variable of automatic storage duration that is either a  non-volatile object or an rvalue reference to a non-volatile object type. In the following  copy-initialization contexts, a move operation might be used instead of a copy operation:
>
> - If the expression in a `return` `([stmt.return])` or `co_­return` `([stmt.return.coroutine])` statement is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names an implicitly movable entity declared in the body or parameter-declaration-clause of the innermost enclosing function or lambda-expression, ...
>
> overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy or the `return_­value` overload to call is first performed as if the expression or operand were an rvalue. ...

Let us consider function template

```
template<typename T>
T f() {
    struct {
        T x;
        operator T&&() && { return static_cast<T&&>(x); }
    } s;
    return s;
}
```

which returns a variable of automatic storage duration `s`. And there is a conversion operator taking rvalue-reference `&&` that can be used to construct function return value of type `T`.

I expected that thanks to above-mentioned rule, it will work for any type `T`. However it did not:

```
struct A{};

int main() {
    // ok in GCC and Clang
    f<A>();
    // error everywhere
    //f<int>();
}
```

Calling `f` with template argument `struct A` works in Clang and GCC, but not in MSVC printing the error:

```
error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'f::<unnamed-type-s>' to 'T' with [T=A]
note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Does MSVC have some bug here?

And calling `f` with template argument `int` does not work anywhere. MSVC's error is the same, and Clang's error now:

```
error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'struct (unnamed struct at <source>:3:5)' to function return type 'int'
note: candidate function not viable: expects an rvalue for object argument
        operator T&&() && { return static_cast<T&&>(x); }
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dfdjEx4v4

Is it expected that the rule works when the function returns class types like `A` and not scalar types like `int`?

Comment: The wording you quoted is already problematic for fundamental types, because they are not initialized by constructors. Might just be a wording defect due to an oversight, but there's that nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah, this is an MSVC bug. You can see [in this reduced example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EeEhbYK8o) that it's calling `operator A&() &` instead of `operator A&&() &&`. MSVC probably doesn't implement [P1155](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1155r3.html) yet.

Comment: @Barry did they consider last use of any automatic object, prior to a `return` too? Wouldn't it be more general? Because that would also cover tail call optimization. Just let last use of any object be xvalue.

Comment: @Red.Wave: Last use (outside of `return`) could be a long time before the end of the object’s lifetime, making it surprising/dangerous for the lifetime of its _contents_ to end (that) early.

Comment: @DavisHerring if there are no living views or refrences to the object, moving it won't hurt anything. Destruction can happen anytime after the moving line returns. Last use can be determined at compile time. The proper definition of last use needs more focus, but it can at least cover the `return` statement and can be traced back to the point where no object - whose initialization statement referenced the target object - is used anymore.

Comment: @Red.Wave: If the object is (or contains) a `std::shared_ptr` to something that owns a lock, moving from it early may very much hurt something.

Comment: @DavisHerring what happens then?? If this the single owner, nobody else should be using the lock; otherwise nothing is happening to the lock

Comment: @Red.Wave: The programmer could easily be depending on the lock being held until the end of the scope because of other operations after the “last use”.

Comment: Then there's a hold refrenece on the object. That reference determines last use.

Comment: @Red.Wave: No language-level reference need exist in such a situation.  If you need an example, ask a question.

Comment: @DavisHerring I'd rather chat. I can't imagine how separate objects can rely on each other without either refrencing other (or a parent referencing both).